# A numbers power between 0 and 1 in C

Tags: c, math, pow

I'm making a program to replace math.h's `pow()` function.
I'm not using any functions from math.h.

The problem is, I can calculate powers as integers like

- 15<sup>-2</sup>
- 45.32<sup>11</sup>

but I can't calculate

- x<sup>2.132</sup>

My program first finds integer power of x (x<sup>2</sup>) and multiplies it by (x<sup>0.132</sup>).

I know that x<sup>0.132</sup> is 1000th root of x to the power 132 but I can't solve it.

**How can I find x<sup>y</sup> (0 < y < 1)**

Comment: One way is to divide the logarithm of x by y, and then use that as the exponent for raising the base of the logarithms: `exp(ln(x)/y)`.  OTOH, that probably isn't all that helpful; it uses different functions from `<math.h>`.

Comment: @MartinR I think it's pretty clear that all the uses of the character ^ in the OP are mathematical exponentiation, not the `^` operator.

Comment: Seems that I misread the question, sorry. Comment deleted.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler i can solve it by creating  exponent and logarithm functions.

Comment: You may find this http://www.netlib.org/fdlibm/ interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compute `x ^ y`, 0 < y < 1 :

1. Approximate `y` as a rational fraction, `(a/b)`

(Easiest way: Pick whatever `b` you want to get sufficient accuracy as a constant.
 Then use: `a = b * y`.)

2. Approximate the `b` root of `y` using any method you like, such as Newton's.

(Simplest way: You know it's between `0` and `b` and can easily tell if a given value is too low or too high. So keep a `min` that starts at zero and a `max` that starts at `b`. Repeatedly try `(min + max) / 2`, see if it's too big or too small, and adjust `min` or `max` appropriately. Repeat until `min` and `max` are nearly the same.)

3. Raise that to the `a` power.

(Possibly by repeatedly multiplying it by itself. Optimize this if you like. For example, `a^4` can be computed with just two multiplications, one to find `a^2` and then one to square it. This generalizes easily.)

Comment: Thank you. Newton's method would be helpful.

Comment: Note that this won't perform particularly well, nor will it handle inf or NaN values correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Use the factorization inherent in floating point formats to split `x=2^e*m` with `1<=m<2` to create the sub-problems `2^(e*y)` and `m^y`

Use square roots, `x^y=sqrt(x)^(2*y)` and if there is an integer part in `2*b`, split that off.

Use the binomial theorem for `x` close to `1`, which will occur when iterating the square root.

```
(1+h)^y=1+y*h+(y*(y-1))/2*h^2+...+binom(y,j)*h^j+...
```

where the quotient from one term to the next is `(y-j)/(j+1)*h`

```
h=x-1;
term = y*h;
sum = 1+term;
j=1;
while(1+term !=1) {
    term *= h*(y-j)/(1+j);
    sum += term;
    j+=1;
}
```